# My quarkus runner jar always starts in blocking mode

Tags: java, jar, jvm, command-line-interface, quarkus

Whenever I build and run an uberjar created using Quarkus plugins, I get a runner jar which starts off as a server, while my app isn't a server, it's a CLI app.

```sh
java -jar ./target/MLPMnist-1.0.0-runner.jar
```

```java
2019-10-15 18:06:51,222 INFO  [io.quarkus] (main) Quarkus 0.23.2 started in 0.876s.
2019-10-15 18:06:51,254 INFO  [io.quarkus] (main) Profile prod activated.
2019-10-15 18:06:51,255 INFO  [io.quarkus] (main) Installed features: [cdi]
(waiting)
```

Also, I haven't included the feature 'cdi' yet it seems to have installed it, how do I not include cdi and how do I make it non-blocking.

No doubt the above information is handy, I'd like to see it but at least my app should run.

Typically I was expecting to see an error like this:

```
--action argument has not been passed in or no valid value has been provided
- Usage:
    ./[command] --action train    --output-dir /path/to/output/dir
    or
    ./[command] --action evaluate --input-dir  /path/to/input/dir
```

I used my inspiration for this project from the Quarkus [getting started simple project](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus-quickstarts/tree/master/getting-started), using the minimal extensions possible. There is no quick way to evaluate which extensions your project would require other than manually going thru the extensions in the guide.

One more question, if you already have a `maven shade plugin` configuration within my origin project, can I merge this configuration with that of Quarkus maven plugin without losing any shade/uberjar related functionalities?

I also tried that as an alternative option and set the `<uberJar></uberJar>` flag to true although I couldn't find enough docs or examples on how to use it in depth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quarkus does not support command line applications yet and thus it always starts as a server.

The CDI/ArC extension is always installed.

So that's what explains the behaviors you have.

Comment: Alas! Will look forward to this support in the future! It's okay to have some default extensions installed as long as they don't come in the way of the functionalities our actual app.